# Is it possible to change the fx between transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm using the jQuery plugin cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) to cycle through displaying some images on my site.

I'd like to change the transition fx (fade, ScrollHorz etc) between transitions

I thought I could do this by attaching a handler to the 'cycle-after' event:

```
$('#myelement').on('cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    console.log('was ' + optionHash.fx); // "was fade"
    optionHash.fx = 'scrollHorz';
    console.log('now ' + optionHash.fx); // "now scrollHorz"
});
```

but changing the value in optionHash has no effect - the fx stays as "fade".

Comment: Hi. First of all you're logging the speed and not the fx. Secondly, there is not such event in jQuery as "cicle-after" so I assume you're using a plugin that isn't mentioned in your description.

Comment: I've added two missing quotes in your source snippet. I'm unsure whether this could have been the original issue that occurred in your project?

Comment: Thanks @AurelioDeRosa! - I've cleaned up the question to make it a bit clearer - I'm using the cycle2 plugin.
I've also fixed the error in the log line.

Comment: I've never used this plugin, but my assumption is that you have to choose the animation when you initialize the plugin, not after.